# Creating the HTML from a code behind variable

Tags: asp.net

Recently I just learned I can do this, where I can set the readonly attribute from my code behind value like this:

```
readonly="<%# someOtherBoolean %>"
```

and used it like this:

```
<textarea 
         name="txtSomeThing" 
         tabindex="1" 
         id="txtSomeThing" 
         style="overflow: auto;" 
         rows="12" 
         cols="80"
         readonly="<%# someOtherBoolean %>">
</textarea>
```

Now in the same page I have something like this and again want to use the same technique but it gives me syntax errors, what should I do and what is different?

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<textarea  style=""overflow:auto"" cols=60 rows=2 ")
```

Which I thought I can change to

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<textarea readonly="<%# someOtherBoolean %>" style=""overflow:auto"" cols=80 rows=4 ")
```

Comment: The first example HAS WORKED

Comment: You don't need to use inline ASP.NET syntax if you're already in C# code. Just do a string concatenate or a format string or string interpolation etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `someOtherBoolean` is already a variable on the code-behind, why use an front-end embedded expression block? You're creating a control from the code-behind, that goes to the front-end, that then searches for a variable on the code-behind. It's a major obfuscation.

Just use the variable from the code-behind:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<textarea readonly='" & someOtherBoolean.ToString() & "' style=""overflow:auto"" cols=80 rows=4 ")
```

Comment: escaping character solution is wrong, it says character constant must contain exactly one character.

Comment: I believe there was a misunderstanding. When you responded to my comment and said that the other method worked, I thought you meant *my* other method. That cleared up thanks to @CDspace, I believe both his and my own answer are what you're looking for. Granted, mine is VB and his is C#, but you didn't include any sort of tag to help us out on that one. Because there are no semi-colons, I'm assuming it's VB.

Comment: yes, thanks. This updated answer works.  I didn't know how to do escape chars like that in VB .

Answer (score 1):

[Embedded Code blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx) are mainly provided for backwards compatability for older ASP systems. There is no need to use them in the code behind in modern systems. The embedded code blocks provide access to program flow and values declared in the code behind while the page being served is built.

In your second example, you don't need to use the embedded code block because *you already have access* to the variable you are trying to use. You can simply write it as

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( "<textarea readonly=\"" + someOtherBoolean.ToString() + "\" style=\"overflow:auto\" cols=80 rows=4 " )
```

Comment: This is pretty much my exact answer, which for one reason or another got downvoted :(

Comment: This is C#, includes a link to the docs, with some extra info, and doesn't include your second, wrong, example

Comment: My answer is VB, which can easily be converted - OP never specified a language. Second, I only included the second answer because OP said *"IT WORKS"* in the comments above when I included it as a comment.

Comment: @Santi Actually I think he was referring to the first example in his own question, and FWIW, I didn't see your answer as I was writing up mine

Comment: I posted two examples in the comments. He commented shortly thereafter saying "The first example HAS WORKED", so I naturally assumed it was in reference to my comment. That being said, I believe both you and I have similar, correct answers.

Comment: Also, my intention wasn't to call you out for posting the same answer, and I apologize if it came off that way. It was more of a "tread lightly" heads-up after I saw my answer was getting down-voted.

Comment: No worries, seeing the same answers pop up within minutes of each other happens all the time around here